# In Miktex with winedt, how to install tikz-cd?

Tags: packages, miktex

To make commutative diagram, I have to use `tikz-cd` package.
The error says `tikz-cd.sty not found`.
So I find `tikz-cd.sty` file, but I can't know where I should put this file.
In my computer, MiKTeX's location is `C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9`

How should I do?

Comment: I already done to update pgf pakege. But Nothing changed....

Comment: Use the package manager to install tikz.

Comment: For add new packages use *MiTeX Package Manager*, it will find this package and properly instal

Comment: I suspect your MiKTeX set up needs to be synced with the servers to allow you to tell it to install the package. Does http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/108447/how-should-one-maintain-and-update-a-miktex-installation help at all?

Answer (score 0):

Place the files in the following directory:

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tikz-cd\
```

or

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tikz-cd\
```

(depending on your installation)